# What is casting a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I know that you can cast a type such as an int to a float but what is casting a pointer?

For example I been looking at some code for Direct X API

`reinterpret_cast<void**>(&mDirect3DDevice)`

I don't understand what happening here. I thought casting was when you basically convent a type to another type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting is indeed converting one type to another type, or more accurately, converting a value of one type to a value of another type.

In your case, you are converting a pointer to whatever `mDirect3DDevice` is to a pointer to `void *`.

Generally, though, reinterpret-casting pointers isn't very useful, since you don't have any guarantees that the result is useful. The only sensible reinterpret casts are:

- to and from `void *`, which are round-trip value-preserving (that is, any object pointer can be converted to a pointer to `void` and back and you get the original value back), but those should be done with `static_cast`s;
- to and from `char *`, which is useful for accessing an objects underlying byte representation (e.g. for serialization);
- between pointers to layout-compatible, standard-layout types (e.g. common intial sequences of unions, or signed versions of integral types).

Reinterpreting pointers *and dereferencing the result* allows you to pretend that a value of one type is in fact a value of another type — and that only makes sense in a very narrow set of circumstances.

Comment: Para 2 should read: you are treating the representation of a pointer to whatever as if it were the representation of a pointer to `void *`. There's no conversion, it is aliasing.   This is UB by the standard, however (presumably) on the platform in question, all pointers have the same representation etc. and the compiler implements an extension to define this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that any variable can be cast as a pointer because a pointer points to the position in memory of that variable. So in this case the `&` before `mDirect3DDevice` returns the memory location of the variable `mDirect3DDevice` instead of the contents of `mDirect3DDevice`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Taking the address of a variable with `&` is not called "casting"... wrong terminology.